# Can I create a single jar which includes src\main packages as well as src\test packages without using assembly plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have pom.xml that generates two jar files one contains src\main packages and the other other has src\test packages.

I am not sure about assembly plugin, so without using it can I build a jar that will have both?

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: I need to publish the jar to the artifactory, my current pom creates two separate jars however I am trying to bundle them in a single jar before publishing it to the artifactory.

Comment: This is very unusual. People either don't publish the test code at all or put it into a separate jar. If you put it in one jar, the classes reside at the same place as the classes from main, so there is no reason to have them in the test directory in the first place.

Comment: I totally agree with you JF Meier. But still is this achievable? If yes, How ?

Comment: Seriously, if you have no reason to do it, don't do it. Or give me a reason, and I try to find a solution for your actual problem.